# Text in the top-right margin on every page

Tags: header-footer

I am trying to put my name in the top-right margin on every page. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\rhead{Eldila}` with the `fancyhdr` package.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the document class or package. Here an example that uses `scrpage2`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ohead{abc}
\begin{document}
\null
\end{document}
```